# Implement Python stack using linked list and access the items in the stack

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, linked-list, stack

I am trying to implement a stack using a linked list. I have written the code below and **MAY YOU PLEASE ASSIST IN IMPROVING THE CODE** I want to Insert the names of big five animals and arrange them in order of size = > as follows Elephant (approximately 5 tonnes +), Rhinoceros
(approximately 2 tonnes), Buffalo (650kg), Lion (225 kg), and Leopard (96kgs).

How do I carry out the following

**1. Return the first and last element (name of animal)
when the elements are sorted in ascending order**

Below is my Code

```
class Node:
     
    # Class to create nodes of linked list
    # constructor initializes node automatically
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
     
class Stack:
     
    # head is default NULL
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
     
    # Checks if stack is empty
    def isempty(self):
        if self.head == None:
            return True
        else:
            return False
     
    # Method to add data to the stack
    # adds to the start of the stack
    def push(self,data):
         
        if self.head == None:
            self.head=Node(data)
             
        else:
            newnode = Node(data)
            newnode.next = self.head
            self.head = newnode

    def find_animal(self, data):
        big_head = self.head
        index = 0
        while big_head.next:
            if big_head.data == data:
                print(f'{big_head.data} at index {index}')

            index += 1
            big_head = big_head.next


    # Remove element that is the current head (start of the stack)
    def pop(self):
         
        if self.isempty():
            return None
             
        else:
            # Removes the head node and makes
            #the preceding one the new head
            poppednode = self.head
            self.head = self.head.next
            poppednode.next = None
            return poppednode.data
     
    # Returns the head node data
    def peek(self):
         
        if self.isempty():
            return None
             
        else:
            return self.head.data
     
    # Prints out the stack    
    def display(self):
         
        iternode = self.head
        if self.isempty():
            print("Stack Underflow")
         
        else:
             
            while(iternode != None):
                 
                print(iternode.data,"->",end = " ")
                iternode = iternode.next
            return
   

# Driver code
The_Big_Five = Stack()
The_Big_Five.push("Leopard")
The_Big_Five.push("Lion") 
The_Big_Five.push("Buffalo") 
The_Big_Five.push("Rhinoceros")
The_Big_Five.push("Elephant")

# Code for printing linked list

The_Big_Five.display()

# Code for sorting the linked list
sorted_Big_5 =sorted(The_Big_Five)

#Printing the sorted list
print(sorted_Big_5)

#Printing the first element of the sorted linked list
print(sorted_Big_5[0])

#printing the last element of the sorted  linked list
print(sorted_Big_5[-1])
```

Comment: This question is too broad. Please focus on *one specific* issue, and explain what goes wrong (one thing!) and how to reproduce that problem.

Comment: @trincot I mainly want to know how to print any selected item in a linked list specifically the first and last element.

Comment: So, can you update your question to make it focused on one problem only, and provide in the question what is needed for us to reproduce the problem? Use the edit link below your question.

Comment: So you want to sort? I don't see in your code where you are trying to sort, and what the problem is you encountered while trying.

Comment: @trincot I don't know how to sort a linked list (That's the code which I need help with) and after sorting I want to print the first and last element. So how can I improve my code so that it can perform what I am intending to do? Kindly asking for your assistance

Comment: @trincot I have re-written my code showing how I am trying to sort the linked list and printing the first and last element but it is saying TypeError: 'Stack' object is not iterable

Comment: `sorted` will not work. Why not make sure you already place every newly inserted item at its sorted place? Then you don't need to call any sorting method afterwards...

Comment: @trincot my question has different parts the first one requires me to insert the elements first then secondly sort the linked list and print the first and last element. It's an assignment question which I am trying to write.  So the main challenge is on sorting the linked list and then printing the first and last element.

Comment: So what have you learned about sorting? Surely this assignment serves for you to implement what you have learned about sorting lists... Which sorting algorithm are you going to use? Bubblesort, mergesort, quicksort, selectionsort, heapsort,...

Comment: @trincot need your help Sir I am still new to these things. But I want to use quicksort

Comment: Sorry, we can help if you try. This is not a free coding service. So show us what you have done to implement quick sort, and where it fails. You put in bold *"assist in improving the code"*, but there is nothing there that relates to sorting, so this is not about improving... you seem to ask us to write the code for you. This is the wrong site for that. We are willing to help, but the effort has to come from both sides.

Comment: Research the subject. For instance, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69790635/how-to-cleanly-use-quicksort-to-sort-linked-list-python/69791135#69791135) is a quick sort implementation for linked lists. You'll need to adapt it to your needs. If you have a problem while implementing it, then ask a focused question about that specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Something you want is not an `Stack`. It's a [`Priority Queue`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) or [`Heap`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)).
2. There are animals heavier than Elephant and lighter than Leopard. How can you figure out which animal will the user push to the stack? so the data you use in `Node` class could be a dictionary with a `size` key in its simplest form.

   ```
   class Node:

        def __init__(self, name: str, size: int):
             animal_data = {'name': name, 'size': size}
             self.data = animal_data
             self.next = None
   ```
3. When you push new data into the `Stack`, you must sort stack by the `size` key in `data` property in `Node` class. So whenever you display the stack, heavier animal will display first.
4. To return the first element, you could use `self.head` property but for the last element, you must change the structure of your linked list. This type of linked list you use is [`Singly Linked List`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_list) but you must use [`Doubly Linked List`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Doubly_linked_list) that has an extra property called `Tail` and different behavior when `Pushing` into and `Popping` from stack.
5. Python has [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) module that implement all you want with `list` . To have a `Heap` with `Linked List`, you must implement it yourself. Also has `deque` module that is an implementation of stack and queue with doubly linked list.

And here you could read more about Heap, Queue and Stack in Python :

- [The Python heapq Module: Using Heaps and Priority Queues](https://realpython.com/python-heapq-module/)
- [Python's deque: Implement Efficient Queues and Stacks](https://realpython.com/python-deque/)
- [Linked Lists in Python: An Introduction](https://realpython.com/linked-lists-python/)

Comment: thank you for the feedback. The question is an assignment I was given which is focusing mainly on Big 5 animals. On item 2 of your responses, you asked me how a user can figure out which animal to push since they are animals bigger than elephants but my focus is mainly on the Big 5 animals ["Elephant", "Rhinoceros", "Lion", "Leopard" ]. So after inserting the animals in a linked list how do I print the first element and the last element after sorting the linked list in ascending order.

Comment: After sorting the list in ascending order, the `self.head` will point to the `Leopard` and `Elephant` will be at the end of the list. so you must iterate throw the list until you reach the end and then you can return the last item. also you can use this trick -> [Find the Kth Node from the end in a given singly Linked List](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/find-the-kth-node-from-the-end-in-a-given-singly-linked-list-using-cplusplus).